# Yahoo Site Explorer API replacement?

Tags: seo, analytics, api

Since the [Yahoo Site Explorer Web Services API is going away at the end of 2010](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/search/siteexplorer/alliance-7.html), are there any other web search APIs that offer similar information?

In particular, I'm interested in services similar to [Inbound Links API](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/siteexplorer/V1/inlinkData.html) and [PageData API](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/siteexplorer/V1/pageData.html).

I've heard a little bit about Majestic SEO, but don't know much about what they can offer in terms of APIs.

Information about them or any other service is much appreciated. :)

Comment: +1 intersting. Do you know (read somewhere) they are gonna shut down also Yahoo site explorer?

Comment: @Marco - I believe that's true. It looks like it may be retired in 2012. http://searchengineland.com/yahoo-microsoft-organic-transition-happening-site-explorer-search-monkey-holding-for-now-48843

Comment: @Virtuosi Media: the evil Monopoly gobbles whatever comes on its road.

Comment: FTA linked above: As part of the transition to Bing content systems, we will be shutting down the Webservices API by the end of 2010.

Comment: Ah, you asked about the regular Site Explorer. Yes, this is going away too. Boo. :(

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [SEOmoz API](http://www.seomoz.org/api). I haven't used it, but I generally find that SEOmoz is a smart company that does their homework, so they would be the first place I would check. They have a [free version](http://apiwiki.seomoz.org/SEOmoz-Free-API) for up to 1 million links, anchor texts, or pages per month and a [paid version](http://apiwiki.seomoz.org/SEOmoz-Site-Intelligence-APIs) for a starting rate of $500/month. They also offer developer accounts, but you need to contact them for access.

**Edit**: Also see [Open Site Explorer](http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the UrlInfo operation on the [Alexa Web Information Service API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AlexaWebInfoService/1-0/ApiReferenceArticle.html), the [Compete API](http://developer.compete.com/) offers similar stuff but I can't see if they have specifically what you're after.  There is a [Google Webmaster Tools API](http://code.google.com/apis/webmastertools/docs/2.0/developers_guide.html) but it doesn't look like it has the information you're after, perhaps you could just use the regular [search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/) with the `link:` or `site:` operator in your search terms.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it's great: http://www.majesticseo.com/

Comment: Unfortunately they do not allow building of new tools based on their data.